Stuck in a loop or stop blinking
I am a beginner in programming and I just started stm32f103c8tr programming. For this task there is a normal LED and blinking LED. I should:

Blink the built-in led (LED1) at a frequency of 2Hz.
Use UART control two leds(LED2 & LED3).
Send only ONE character to determine which LED is on as follows:-


a) If the character sent is between ‘a’ to ‘m’, toggle LED2
b) If the character sent is between ‘n’ to ‘z’, blink LED3 with 200ms
c) If the character sent is ‘0’, turn off both LED2 and LED3


All characters sent should be in lower case.
Send responses back to your terminal which operation is running (from the above bullet points) for every 500ms.

The problem is in the code where if LED1 values is inserted, it will stop Blinking of LED or some other problem. What can I do? This is the code:-
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2024 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include <string.h>

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint8_t RXdata;
volatile uint8_t new_data_received = 0;
volatile uint8_t tired = 0;
volatile uint8_t untired = 1;



/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, &RXdata, 1);  // Start UART receive interrupt

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {




       while (!new_data_received){

                     HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2);
                     HAL_Delay(200);


               char *response2 = "b\n";
               HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)response2, strlen(response2), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
               HAL_Delay(500);
                }



      while(tired && untired ){
                  char *response1 = "a\n";
                  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)response1, strlen(response1), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
                  HAL_Delay(500);

                  }


     while(!tired && untired){
          char *response3 = "c\n";
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)response3, strlen(response3), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
          HAL_Delay(500);
          }




    }


    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /* Configure GPIO pin : PA2 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* Configure GPIO pin : PB10 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)

{
  if (huart->Instance == USART1)
  {

      if (RXdata > 96 && RXdata < 110)  // ASCII value from 'a' to 'm'
      {

          HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_10);
          tired = 1;
          untired = 1;


      }

      if (RXdata > 109 && RXdata < 123)
                    // ASCII value from 'n' to 'z'
                  {
                      new_data_received = 0;
                      untired = 0;
                  }

      if (RXdata == 48){

          new_data_received = 1;
          tired = 0;
          untired = 1;

          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_10, 0);
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, 0);




         }

      }


    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, &RXdata, 1);

    // Re-enable UART receive interrupt
  }


/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
}

I tried any way that I know of and I should stop message of 'b' without stop the blinking.

Your habit of using lots of whitespace and your inconsistent indentation is irritating for me and might hinder you in analysis of structures like loops. Consider cleaning that up.

Does HAL_Delay() function is blocking? If so, you spend most of the time doing nothing and without running the actual code

Furthermore, you talks about three LEDs, but I see only two GPIOs involved. Please, clarify in the question each LED to what GPIO pin is connected
